# How to do validation in EditText within a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have problem in validating Edittext in listview in onFocusChangeListner.

My UI looks like this

```
MeterName Previous CurrentReading
Meter1    100      Here i want to type current reading
```

When I type the current Reading it will compare with previous reading. Current Reading can't be less than Previous. If it is less than previous then I want to alert the user and  focus is on same EditBox.

My code is here:

```
 public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

          try {
            Previous_Reading = getArray_Meter_Reading.getJSONObject(holder.ref)
                        .getString("PrevMeterReading").toString();
            Cumulative = getArray_Meter_Reading
                    .getJSONObject(holder.ref).getString("Cumulative")
                    .toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



           if(!hasFocus){

               int Current=Integer.valueOf(holder.adp_Current.getText().toString());
               Previous=Integer.parseInt(Previous_Reading);
                if(Current<  Previous ){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);
                    builder.setTitle("WARNING");
                    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                    builder.setMessage("Please Enter UserName");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {

                                    // Caption.requestFocus();

                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog diag = builder.create();
                    diag.show();
                }

           }

      } });
```

With this code, when I start typing in EditBox alert is shown for all the characters, what I type like if previous is 600 and I type current reading like 6 it shows me alertdialog then
5 again alertdialog till it is greater than previous value.

When I click on EditText hasFocus is true and when I type any number say 5 focus changes to false.

Can any one tell me how to do validation for that by giving sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2011/11/23/android-validation-with-edittext/) . Then, extending that concept to your problem, I would suggest:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
int textValue = 0 ;
try {
    textValue = Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString()) ;
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // Handle the exception
}
if (textValue < minValue) {
    myEditText.requestFocus();
    myEditText.setError( "Value entered is lower than previous value." );
}
```

Comment: how can get hole text from editbox at once and then validate it wit previous value because , when i type any single number onfocuschangeListner get call and error message prompts for all the numbers till it is greater than previous.

Answer (score 4):

its better to use on textwatcher for your edittext.

```
 edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)   
              {
                 if(Integer.valueOf(holder.adp_Current.getText().toString()<Integer.parseInt(Previous_Reading)){
                 edittext.seterror("your error message");

            }

            @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,   int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: but in TextWatcher it gives me java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer and one more i want to tell all type every digit it give me an error message .